# Objective c - getting exc_bad_access when trying to copy NSArray in queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to copy an array inside a specific queue and sometimes my app crashes with `exc_bad_access`.

```
- (NSArray *)safeCopyArrayInQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue andArray:(NSArray *)arrayToCopy {
    __block NSArray *copy = nil;
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        @try {
            copy = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayToCopy]; // this line crashes
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"%@", exception.description);
            copy = @[];
        }
    });

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: is ARC disabled?

Comment: yes, enabled @RohanBhale

Comment: what about the reference of the array that you are passing in arrayToCopy? Is it being used in other threads and being changed over time? Specifically avoid using instance of NSArray in different threads, if its mutable.

Comment: I have two `dispatch_queue_t`. The first one (let's call it `queue1`) is using and changing the array over time (sometimes re-allocates it) and the second one calls this method. when it calls this method, it passes `queue1` and the array as parameters

Comment: I cannot say specifically without viewing the code in the other queue. There could be a chance of the array being referenced by arrayToCopy to be deallocated before you use it  in +[NSArray arrayWithArray:] method.

Comment: Do you still have the question? You kind of answered it yourself in the last comment. If you want to access the same memory at the same time across threads, you need to use some kind of locking to allow only one thread accessing at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue thanks to [Rohan Bhale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437015/rohan-bhale) - the problem occurred because I passed the array as a parameter and it was deallocated before I used it in [NSArray arrayWithArray:] method.

To fix it I used the array as a class variable and access it only inside its queue.